# Kivy is very slow at launch

Tags: python, kivy

When I start my app, kivy is very slow. It loads all the parts several times. How could I reduce loading times and optimize code?

My full code :

https://pastebin.com/Cj6QL9eD

Here's the output of the console

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\acer\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-10-07_34.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\acer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\acer\anaconda3\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Audio       ] Providers: audio_sdl2 (audio_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.0.0 - Build 10.18.10.4358'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.00 - Build 10.18.10.4358'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[WARNING] Deprecated property "<AliasProperty name=filename>" of object "<kivy.core.audio.audio_sdl2.SoundSDL2 object at 0x000002657AD77128>" was accessed, it will be removed in a future version
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Unpack subimage support is available
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] Read <Texture/blitz.glsl>
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] Read <Texture/blitz.glsl>
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] Read <Texture/blitz.glsl>
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] Read <Texture/blitz.glsl>
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] Read <Texture/blitz.glsl>
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [WindowSDL   ] exiting mainloop and closing.
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

Comment: How long does a trivial Kivy app take to start (as in just App().run())? Is it much faster?

Comment: If you have images that are associated with your app, I would shrink them to a reasonable size (800kb) to make the app load a lot faster.

Comment: @inclement No, it takes the same time

Comment: @LucioRandy The size of the images is less than 800 kb

Comment: If a trivial app takes the same time, then the slowness is from Kivy alone, not from your app.